# The MySQL80 service on Local Computer started and then stopped and cant create local file

Tags: mysql

When I try to start the MySQL80 service it gives the following warning "The MySQL57 service on Local Computer started and then stopped and cant create local file". When reading answers on the forum, I came to the conclusion that the problem may be this:

in the directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin when using the command: mysqld --initialize --console

I get the following error:

2022-02-20T20:38:43.800979Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.28) initializing of server in progress as process 6148
2022-02-20T20:38:43.818861Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-02-20T20:38:43.822839Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012576] [InnoDB] Unable to create temporary file inside "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp"; error: 2
2022-02-20T20:38:43.822946Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012929] [InnoDB] InnoDB Database creation was aborted with error Generic error. You may need to delete the ibdata1 file before trying to start up again.
2022-02-20T20:38:43.823742Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-02-20T20:38:43.823838Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013455] [Server] The newly created data directory C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\ by --initialize is unusable. You can remove it.
2022-02-20T20:38:43.824250Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-02-20T20:38:43.824822Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28) MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: Did this get answered? I'm having the exact same issue.